# on-the-fly encoding of TGA image files to video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

A software we use generate 60 TGA files per second and we want to build a video from these files. At the moment we do it with a homemade solution but I have a feeling ffmpeg would do it much better. Indeed videos generated from the same TGA files are smaller in spite of using the same codec parameters.

We can't afford to wait for all the image files to be created, as we need the process to be as fast and as light as possible.

How do I use ffmpeg to encode a video from files generated on-the-fly by the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can use a pipe. Example using `cat` as a substitute for your TGA generator:

```
cat *.tga | ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -c:v targa -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 320x240 -framerate 24 -frame_size 38781 -i - output.mkv
```

Unfortunately you'll have to know the size, in bytes, of each frame ahead of time due to a lack of a TARGA parser as mentioned in [FFmpeg Bug #3614: Targa doesn't work with image2pipe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3614). I'm guessing each frame will be the same size, so just do a test run to get the proper value.

Comment: When using this method, make sure your s/w doesn't apply RLE to the Targa output, else frame sizes will differ.

Comment: sould this work with windows ? I found very little documentation for ffmpeg and pipes under windows

Comment: @Proviste Yes, it should work in Windows.

Comment: Should frame size be the number of pixels, the number of bytes of image data, or the total bytes per frame including file headers?